# how to use function (chart) in react?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm setting up a HightCharts in react, and want to use function (chart).

I want to use it in react.

```
function (chart){
chart.renderer.label().css().attr().add()
}
```

in simple js its easy to use like below

```
$('#container').highcharts({},function (chart){
chart.renderer.label().css().attr().add()
};
```

how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the `highcharts-react-official` wrapper you can take advantage of the `callback` option to call the function:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HighchartsReact
        ...
        callback={function(chart) {
          chart.renderer.label().css().attr().add()
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/wolq576wo5

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#callback

Comment: render() { Mylabel="This is a label"; return ( <div> <HighchartsReact ... callback={function(chart) { chart.renderer.label(Mylabel, 30, 2, 'callout').css({}) .attr({ padding: 8, r: 5, zIndex: 6 }).add(); }} /> </div> ); }
i want to change text of Mylabel when update graph. I tried to use this.state.mylabel but it give error.

Comment: Hi @Wajid Afridi, In this case is better to use the chart `render` event. Please checl this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/x3y9pl4n7p

Comment: i have tried this, data is updating but label didn't change.

Comment: @Wajid Afridi, Please recreate that problem in codesandbox.

Comment: Hi @Wajid Afridi, The events are not updated because of this bug: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6538. Please check a slightly different approach to the topic: https://codesandbox.io/s/73oyq4l0qj

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a library like [Highcharts React](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react), which is a Highcharts wrapper for React. The implementation would be something like this in your class:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.chartRef = React.createRef();

  // Reference could could then be called somewhere else
  this.chartRef.renderer.label().css().attr().add();
}

render() {
  return (
    <HighchartsReact
      highcharts={ Highcharts }
      options={ options }
      ref={ this.chartRef }
    />
  );
}
```